# How do I make a GroovyShell have access to my applications classes?

Tags: groovy

How do I make a GroovyShell have access to my applications classes? I've got it working where I can say simple stuff like `println('5')`, but I can't access any of my classes like `MyClass.printStuff()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wrote the import statements?

Comment: Jep, sometimes you can't see the woods for the trees. ;)